# Crossover two NumPy arrays efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to crossover (swap tails at index 'x') two NumPy arrays with the least computational and memory effort.
Currently I do it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.zeros(10)
a2 = np.ones(10)
x = np.random.randint(1, a1.size)
a1[:x], a2[:x] = a2[:x].copy(), a1[:x].copy()
```

Is there any way to avoid the copy statement, no matter whether crossover is done in-place? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `tmp` variable to save one `copying` -

```
tmp = a2[:x].copy()
a2[:x], a1[:x]  = a1[:x], tmp
```

Sample run -

1) At start (before assigning) :

```
In [322]: a1
Out[322]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [323]: a2
Out[323]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

In [324]: x
Out[324]: 4
```

2) Proposed codes :

```
In [325]: tmp = a2[:x].copy()
     ...: a2[:x], a1[:x]  = a1[:x], tmp
     ...:
```

3) Verify results :

```
In [326]: a1
Out[326]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [327]: a2
Out[327]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```